# Xamarin forms android go back toolbar disappear

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-toolbar, xamarin.forms

got a problem. if i press back on a android device, it goes back to the previews side, but it remove the toolbar for the tabs, anyone got a idea what that could be?

this is how i navigate to a page. which working,

```
            this.Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilPage())
                .ContinueWith(t => { this.Navigation.RemovePage(this); });
```

Then when i press the back button, it goes back, but remove the sites toolbar,

Anyone got any knowledge about this? thanks for your time

Comment: Is `ProfilePage` within a `TabbedPage`? And is the toolbar that is disappearing the `TabbedPage`'s toolbar? Or is the toolbar you are referring to the navigation bar?

Comment: The profilepage is a contentpage within a navigation page.
And what i mean with toolbar is the contentpage's ToolbarItems

Comment: Have you tried not using `ContinueWith()`? Usually when I want to do something after popping/pushing a page, I will either simply put the code right after `PushAsync()` or I will use the `MessagingCenter` to send a message to the page that I am pushing to or popping back to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. tried that. but didn't make any difference

Comment: Are you sure that the `ProfilePage()` does not have code that removes the toolbar? Such as `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Comment: Yes, if it did,. there would be a toolbar to begin with. an it's working on wp8

Answer (score 0):

It's how you are navigating, try navigating with `NavigationPage`

```
this.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(ProfilPage()) )
.ContinueWith(t => { this.Navigation.RemovePage(this); });
```